# What is a formal power series?

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series

First of all, I have read various documents about formal power series. Honestly, I still don't quite understand what it is. I hope to get clarification.

But from what I understand, formal power series can be viewed from two perspectives:

First, constructing these power series as an algebraic structure. Then defining a norm for it. Afterward, determining its convergence. The following link provides a comprehensive article on this perspective:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/2205.00879.pdf

Second, after defining the formal power series with operations, they are then used. If needed to compute at a certain position, they are treated as power series in calculus (with the requirement that the value falls within the convergence domain). I have encountered this perspective in many documents.

I find it challenging to accept the second perspective, transitioning from an algebraic structure to calculus with a convention. Is that my lack of understanding?

I wonder, with the first perspective, if the norm that leads to convergence coincides with the convergence of the power series in calculus?

Thank you!

(I have also read similar questions on the forum, but I still don't understand. That's why I posted this.)

Comment: There is some juggling of homomorphisms going on here that takes some getting used to. While in general we cannot define the evaluation of formal power series at any point (other than zero), any particular formal power series over $\mathbb{C}$ which has a positive radius of convergence can also be interpreted as an actual, non-formal power series, defining a holomorphic function on some disk, and one can do analysis with this actual function. The ring of formal power series contains various subrings of formal power series with various radii of convergence and these admit homomorphisms into...

Comment: ...various rings of holomorphic functions. So one has to move between at least $3$ different rings here. But it does all work out. As for your last question, no, convergence for formal power series is different.

Comment: Why do you think you need a "norm" to construct formal power series?  You can construct the projective limit inside the product.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan 
I'm sorry, but I don't understand the explanation. Could you please help me review the following article?
https://arxiv.org/pdf/2205.00879.pdf
Does the article establish a standard for exponential sequences and then calculate convergence? What is its purpose? Can I substitute X with a value according to the construction in the article?

Comment: a formal power series is an element of a kind of ring, so you don't need a topology nor some analytical tool to define it. Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#The_ring_of_formal_power_series)

Comment: The convergence discussed in the paper is talking about whether an infinite sum of formal power series converges to another formal power series, not the convergence of one formal power series as we do with Taylor series. A formal power series is useful even if the corresponding Taylor series has radius of convergence zero.

Comment: @Math_fun2006: that document entirely concerns formal power series. $X$ never takes a value given by a nonzero complex number. However it does describe composition $f(g(X))$ of formal power series, which can be done entirely formally as long as $g(0) = 0$.